# React fails to add the same item to the list after removing it

Tags: html, reactjs, arrays

I have a hook array that can add items when clicking and selecting which one you want from a select list, and also remove on a button click but when I remove an item and try to add it right after, it is not added to the list but if I add another item and try to add again it works normally.

div that adds the item on the array

```
import foods from 'json/foods'

const [meal, setMeal] = useState([])
let id;

return(
    <div>
            <div>
                // displays all the meals on the screen
                {meal.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <div >
                            <p>Protein:{item.protein}</p>
                            <p>Fats:{item.fats}</p>
                            <p>Carbs:{item.carbs}</p>
                            //icon that on click removes the meal
                            <IoIosRemoveCircle onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div>
                // select where you have all the meal to choose from
                <select onChange={updatesValue} >
                    <option></option>
                    {foods.map((food) => {

                        return <option key={food.id}>{food.name}</option>
                    })}
                </select>
                // button that adds the option selected on the meal array
                <button onClick={() => {
                    for (let i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
                        for (let j = 0; j < meal.length; j++) {
                            if (id === meal[j].name) {
                                // i am going to make a prompt show here instead of this log
                                return console.log('You can´t add two itens of the same value');
                            }
                        }
                        if (id === food[i].name) {
                            setMeal(meal.concat(foods[i]))
                        }
                    }
                }}> Add</button>
            </div>
)
```

Update value function

```
function updateValue(event) {
        id = event.target.value
    }
```

Remove item function

```
 function removeItem(id) {
        const newList = meal.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        setMeal(NewList)
    }
```

I am new to react and i can´t make this work, i just need to be able to add the item again rigth after removing it.

Comment: can you create a https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new with some data to replicate the issue?

Comment: i solved the problem after changing a bit how it works, the select only changes value if i click other option so by clicking on the same one the onChange function is not activated.

Answer (score 0):

The select only changes value if i click other option so by clicking on the same one the onChange function is not activated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).